# SQL: Primary and foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am creating a table that has two values that are both primary and foreign at the same time. I do not know how to create them in SQL. Here is what I did but I get the error, there must only be one primary key. what is the correct way?

```
  CREATE TABLE movie_director(
    director_id CHAR(8)
    constraint pk_director_id_movie_director
    PRIMARY KEY
    constraint fk_director_id_movie_director
    REFERENCES director,
    movie_id VARCHAR(30)
    constraint pk_movie_id_movie_director
    PRIMARY KEY
    constraint fk_movie_id_movie_director
    REFERENCES movie





)
```

Comment: You can try it work in your sql*plus session.

Comment: wrong table look again

Comment: It's certainly **A** way to do this. Any time that the same field is used as primary key on multiple tables I get a bit uncomfortable. Is there a need to reference movie directors through a foreign key relationship? If not I'd suggest having `MOVIES` as a Yes/No field on the `DIRECTOR` table, with perhaps other similar attributes such as `PLAYS`, `COMMERCIALS`, etc.

Comment: It is mandatory, and I have updated it with my full code for the table. I get an error that there can only be one primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is a compound primary key. Change your table definition to something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE movie_director(
  director_id CHAR(8)
    constraint fk_director_id_movie_director
    REFERENCES director,
  movie_id VARCHAR(30)
    constraint fk_movie_id_movie_director
    REFERENCES movie,
  CONSTRAINT PK_MOVIE_DIRECTOR
    PRIMARY KEY (DIRECTOR_ID, MOVIE_ID));
```

Comment: Why do i get invalid data type

Comment: How are the columns `DIRECTOR.DIRECTOR_ID` and `MOVIE.MOVIE_ID` defined?

Comment: director_id CHAR(8)
         CONSTRAINT pk_director_id_director
             PRIMARY KEY,

Comment: movie_id VARCHAR2(30)
    constraint pk_movie_id_movie
        primary key,

Comment: In that case you might try changing the data type of MOVIE_DIRECTOR.MOVE_ID to VARCHAR2 (instead of VARCHAR). I wouldn't think it would matter, but the ways of Oracle are strange and not for mortal man to comprehend... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems pretty clear. There can only be one `PRIMARY KEY` on a table.

You need to create a `COMPOUND PRIMARY KEY` which consists of two columns `(director_id,movie_id)`.

From [wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key)

> In database design, a compound key is a key that consists of two or more attributes that uniquely identify an entity occurrence.